# Android App and Pattern Lock Screen

Tags: android

I am currently developing an app for android 2.2 or above.

I want to allow the user to enable a login before having access to the app. I want to allow the user to choose between various types of login like password, pin or pattern.

I was wondering if would be possible to add a pattern lock to my own app. Is there a plugin I can use to create one or use android's pattern lock for my own app. I only want this for the app I don't want it to change how the actual device is locked.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why wouldn't you look into Android source code, to get [one](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/)?

Comment: [check this library](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/android-lock-pattern/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dont think there is a widget for this. I would create a matrix of images 3x3 give them each a listener and keep track of the order the user presses them. Then take the order, 2,3,6,5,8 for example, save them as a string "23658" this is the password! hash and save that somewhere. whenever a user inputs the button order compare the input hash to the saved one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this sounds like a good idea. Will give it a try

Comment: I tried with your idea.I created a  matrix of images 3x3 gave them each a onTouch listener. The main problem is an user has to touch all button separately to create a pattern, dragging a pattern is not supported.. Any further idea?

Answer (score 2):

If any body is still searching for the answer, I found this library which is pretty useful and much better than the android-lockpattern, hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/PatternLock)

Comment: can you tell me how did you implement this library in your code

Answer (score 1):

There is source for this though:
http://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/source/browse/src/group/pals/android/lib/ui/lockpattern/widget/LockPatternUtils.java?r=7470bc287cba61198430e3d8aff32196bb5824a0