# Can I make Pattern Password Screen Locker android app

Tags: android, pattern-matching, password-protection

Has anyone got experience with developing an application to replace the default lock screen? I've been told it is not possible, however [this](http://www.1mobile.com/pattern-password-screen-locker-849722.html) application manages it.

Any tutorials or guidance you know of would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the best Android Pattern Locker code :        http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/android-lock-pattern/

Comment: @Arshu link not found

Comment: @nida : Follow these links: https://github.com/coderkiss/AppLock
                      
https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/

Answer (score 1):

100% possible. Here are some links to get you started.

[Android App and Pattern Lock Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172551/android-app-and-pattern-lock-screen?rq=1)

[Android Lock Screen Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget?rq=1)

[Developing a custom lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529608/developing-a-custom-lock-screen?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement deviceAdminReciever to use device locks and all please have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) it explains everything about locks setting passwords.....

**Update:**

Use this library  [Link](http://dl.bintray.com/hai%20bison%20apps/android/android-lockpattern/android-lockpattern_v2.8_src.7z)

and Source [Here..](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/source/browse/)

Comment: That link is no good, android 2.2 is out of date. Plus it wasnt until recently you could use the pattern matching api's. Read what the link you posted says "Device Administration API currently only supports passwords for screen lock"

Comment: know check my answere

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

[lockscreenswitchwidget](http://code.google.com/p/futonic-lockscreenswitchwidget/source/browse/)

Comment: please expand your answere link only answeres are ussually down-voted